# Why tk.Button.configure after tkFileDialog.askopenfilename takes effect only after the method is left?

Tags: python, tkinter

In the following code excerpt, which draws a simple GUI with one tick box and a button, I'd like to change the button description and its relief after the button is pressed and the user has selected a file (which is followed by a time consuming calculation).

The button called `select_master_button` is bound to the command `SelectMaster`.

In the `SelectMaster` method the `configure` button instruction is placed directly after the `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` invocation.

The idea is to have the button's description and the relief changed so that the user is aware of the processing activity.

However, when the user selects a file and leaves the file dialog there is no change in the button configuration and only after the whole method is finished the button configuration takes effect.

In this example the last instruction reverts the button's relief and tells the user that the file selection is active. This of course works fine, since it is the last instruction before the method is left.

**Why `tk.Button.configure` after `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` takes effect only after the method is left?**

I'm on Python 2.7.

I understand that placing the button `configure` instruction before the file dialog would provide the remedy but I'd like to understand the current behaviour still.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self, parent):
            self.sort_tick_value = tk.IntVar()
            self.sort_tick_value.set(1)

            ### GUI ###

            self.myParent = parent
            self.myParent.geometry("400x400")

            self.myContainer = tk.Frame(parent)
            self.myContainer.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10, pady=5,
                                  ipadx=5, ipady=5)

            self.sort_selection_frame = tk.Frame(self.myContainer)
            self.sort_selection_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.BOTH,
                                           pady=10)

            self.select_master_frame = tk.Frame(self.myContainer)
            self.select_master_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.BOTH,
                                          pady=10)

            #### Tick Box ####

            self.sort_tick_box =tk.Checkbutton(self.sort_selection_frame,
                                               text="Sort in groups",
                                               variable=self.sort_tick_value)
            self.sort_tick_box.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.W)

            #### Choose Master File Button ####

            self.select_master_button =  tk.Button(self.select_master_frame)
            self.select_master_button.configure(text="Select master file - "
                                                     ".xlsx\n(optional)",
                                                     command=self.SelectMaster)
            self.select_master_button.pack(side = tk.TOP, anchor=tk.N)

    def SelectMaster(self):
        selected_master = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
                parent=root, title='Choose the master file', initialdir = 'D:/')

        self.select_master_button.configure(text="Select master file - "
                                                 ".xlsx\n(scanning file, "
                                                 "please wait)", relief=tk.SUNKEN)

        print "Scanning the selected master file ..."

        wb = load_workbook(selected_master, read_only=True)
        ws = wb.active

        while …:
          # time consuming calculation ...

        self.select_master_button.configure(text="Select master file\n(active)",
                                            relief=tk.RAISED)

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Title“)
myApp = MyApp(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is how all GUIs work. `mainloop` calls many functions in order - first it gets mouse/keyboard event, next it sends it to widget, they call your function, etc., and at the end mainloop redraws widgets (if it is needed). You can use [root.update()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) to force mainloop to redraw widgets.

Comment: If you want to force the display to be updated as soon as possible, call [`root.update_idletasks()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) immediately following your `self.select_master_button.configure()` call. Note: `update_idletasks()` is one of many  [universal widget methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Comment: @furas
@martineau

Thank you both for explaining about the mainloop and the hint with the root.update_idletasks() which works perfectly fine by the way! :)


I understand that the `self.select_master_button.configure()` being effective before the `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` without an update but not after is related to the FiledDialog opening another frame and forcing other widgets to wait for idle to update.